# creating a list from dropdown option

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

i have a dropdown list labeled status and i wanted to add the following options to the drop down:

```
Open
Closed
All
```

for each option a stored procedure will be used generate the results. I just blanked on how add options to the dropdown list without populating them from a table.

Asp.net project, mvc/c#

Comment: which version of asp.net mvc are you using?

Comment: Interesting story. So um, what's the problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlExample" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Open"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Closed"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="All"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

If you want to specify a different value, you can delcare that within the ListItem row

... If you need to add in the code behind:

```
        ddlExample.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Open"));
        ddlExample.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem("Closed"));
        ddlExample.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem("All"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the sample it helped me gather my thoughts

Comment: this is what i did after looking at ur sample: 

viewModel.Status = new[]
                                   {
                                       new SelectListItem {Text = "All", Value = "0"},
                                       new SelectListItem {Text = "Open", Value = "1"},
                                       new SelectListItem {Text = "Closed", Value = "2"},
                                   };
            return viewData;

Answer (score 0):

No need to write space constructions for the simple things, just plain html.. :

```
<select id="selectId" name="selectName">
  <option value="0" selected="">Open</option>
  <option value="1">Closed</option>
  <option value="2">All</option>
<select>
```

So, i see only one reason to add List of `SelectListItem` to a model -- if you want use DataAnnotations for validation.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at Ray K. sample i was able to form the following which i think flows with how the rest of my dropdown boxes are displayed:

```
viewModel.Status = new[]
                               {
                                   new SelectListItem {Text = "All", Value = "0"},
                                   new SelectListItem {Text = "Open", Value = "1"},
                                   new SelectListItem {Text = "Closed", Value = "2"},
                               };
        return viewData;
```

Thanks again Ray K.